# How can I wrap a given number within a given [range)?

Tags: swift, math, numbers, range, pseudocode

I'm trying to write a function which wraps an input value within an input range (inclusive lower-bound, exclusive upper-bound), so that the output value is always within that range.

For example, `4.9.wrapped(within: 3..<5) == 4.9`, and `5.wrapped(within: 3..<5) == 3`.
(`3..<5` is Swift syntax for `[3, 5)`).

I wrote the below algorithm, which *almost* works perfectly, except when the input value is less than the lower-bound of the input range, then the output's inclusivity flips.

For example, when the input range is `[3, 5)` and the input value is `20`, then the range output correctly reflects as `[3, 5)` in the output, but when the input value is `1` with the same input range, then the output incorrectly reflects a `(3, 5]` range.

#### Example code in Swift

```swift
public extension FloatingPoint {
    
    func wrapped(within range: Range<Self>) -> Self {
        
        let breadth = range.upperBound - range.lowerBound
        
        let offset: Self 
        if self < range.lowerBound {
            offset = breadth
        }
        else {
            offset = 0
        }
        
        let baseResult = (self - range.lowerBound).truncatingRemainder(dividingBy: breadth)

        return baseResult + range.lowerBound + offset
    }
}
```

#### Example code as pseudocode

```
function (value: Number, rangeLowerBoundInclusive: Number, rangeUpperBoundExclusive: Number) returns Number {

    let breadth be (rangeUpperBoundExclusive - rangeLowerBoundInclusive)

    if (value is less than rangeLowerBoundInclusive)
        let offset be breadth
    else
        let offset be 0

    let baseResult be ((value - rangeLowerBoundInclusive) mod breadth)
    
    return baseResult + rangeLowerBoundInclusive + offset
}
```

#### Output Visualization

Here is a visualization of the output for all input values from `-10` to `10`, stepping `0.1` at a time, with the range `[3, 5)`:

[image: A sawtooth graph, showing the incorrect behavior described by this question.]

As you can see, the input values less than `3.0` all appear within the range `(3, 5]`, and the input values greater than or equal to `3.0` all appear within the range `[3, 5)`. **Why is this, and how can I make it so that all values are within `[3, 5)`?**

Comment: Are you sure the underlying algorithm is correct and this is a code issue?

Comment: I don't think I stated anything about an underlying algorithm nor its correctness

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The edge case is when `self - lowerBound` is divisible by `breadth` at **left side** of the range.

In this situation, `baseResult` is `0`, your code will wrongly add offset of `breadth`, then the result becomes `5`.

You want to return `lowerBound + baseResult + breadth` only when `baseResult < 0` (different from your code: `self < range.lowerBound`).